# How to create a curl conection to Sendle API

Tags: php, curl, sendle

Hopefully an easy question, the [Sendle](https://api-doc.sendle.com/#testing-authentication) documentation gives the following curl code:

```
  curl 'https://api.sendle.com/api/ping'
  -u sendleID:APIKey
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -H "Accept: application/json"
```

php.net document for [Basic curl example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) shows:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch)) {
    fwrite($fp, curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

How do I convert the sendle code to php code?

Possibly more specifically, how to convert the options, -u -H, into curl_setopt().

Comment: Paste the cURL code in at https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ and you should get a pretty accurate conversion

Comment: If you had posted this as an answer with example this would have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure but mainly I just wanted to point out that you can solve it yourself easily if you have a similar requirement in future

Comment: @ADyson of course, but the standard of StackOverflow is to post code, not links. As someone looking at this down the line doesn't have to be concerned with broken links and will always have the code available.

Comment: That's why it was posted as a comment, not an answer. I was giving you the tool to find the answer, not the answer itself. Give a man a fish, and all that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example above, try this:

```
$url = "https://api.sendle.com/api/ping";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sendleID:APIKey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode == '200') {
   // use $result
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be the solution. I'm getting the error "Error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" which seems correct from my dev system. I'm confident this will work when I get it up on my live testing site.

Comment: This code will not work. Follow this url : https://developers.sendle.com/reference/ping

Answer (score 0):

Sendle also provide this code
Follow this url : https://developers.sendle.com/reference/ping

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://sandbox.sendle.com/api/ping",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: Basic sendleID:APIKey"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```